# Is "Structure of algebras" (A. A. Albert ) a good introduction to algebras over fields"

Tags: book-recommendation

I'm looking for books about algebras over fields. At present, I'm reading the Schafer book. I found "Structure of algebras" by A. Adrian Albert; would you recommend it?

By the way, is there any other good book about algebras? Could you give a recommendation?

Comment: Associative Algebras - Robert Pierce is another you could take a look at, although it is broader in the sense that it studies algebras over commutative rings rather than fields